# make matplotlib fill_between overwrite the subplot in front

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

I am trying to plot several lines which partially overlap and occlude each other.  This is what I tried:

```py
# Create the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# remove grid
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

# define data 
X = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 400) 
Y1 = np.cos(2*X)
Y2 = X**2/10-0.5

ax.plot(X, Y1, lw=1)
ax.fill_between(X, Y1, -1, facecolor=(1,0,0,1))

ax.plot(X, Y2)
ax.fill_between(X, Y2, -1, facecolor=(1,1,1,1))

plt.show()
```

which produces

[image: what I get]

but when the second `fill_between` goes down to -1, I would like it to also occlude the blue graph.  Like so:

[image: what i want]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Use `zorder=3`for the second fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with @JohanC's suggestion, as it makes it easier to generalize to more graphs.  So for example

```py
ax.plot(X, Y1, lw=1)
ax.fill_between(X, Y1, -1, facecolor=(1,0,0,1), zorder=2)

ax.plot(X, Y2)
ax.fill_between(X, Y2, -1, facecolor=(1,1,1,1), zorder=3)

ax.plot(X, Y3, lw=1, zorder=1)
ax.fill_between(X, Y3, -1, facecolor=(0,0,1,1), zorder=1)


ax.plot(X, Y4, lw=1, zorder=0)
ax.fill_between(X, Y4, -1, facecolor=(0,1,0,0.5), zorder=0)
```

Can plot something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
# Create the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# remove grid
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

# define data 
X = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 400) 
Y1 = np.cos(2*X)
Y2 = X**2/10-0.5

# NEW #########################
for i in range(Y1.size):
    if Y1[i] < Y2[i] :
        Y1[i] = Y2[i]
###############################

ax.plot(X, Y1, lw=1, color="blue")
ax.fill_between(X, Y1, -1, facecolor=(1,0,0,1))

ax.plot(X, Y2, color="orange")
ax.fill_between(X, Y2, -1, facecolor=(1,1,1,1))

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Graph]

Basically at any point Y1 is less than Y2 we set the point on Y1 equal to Y2.

Comment: That's a creative solution!  In the end I went with `zorder` as suggested by @JohanC ... since it makes it easier if there are more plots